# Image not scaling to full width of div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a div element and I want my image within it to scale to the full width of the parent however for some reason its not taking up the full width. I could use object-fit: cover; but I don't want to crop the image I want it to fill up the space of the parent. Id also like to scale it so it remains a square the whole time so it always scales as an equal square. I am a little confused as to why its not taking up the parents container. It seems to be wanting to keep its aspect ratio but I want it to stretch to the parent container both via its height and width properties.

[image]

html:

```
import React from 'react';

const ThreeGridTeaser = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className="specific-offer-container mt-0">
            <div className="three-grid-teaser-wrapper">
                <div className="three-grid-teaser-container">
                    {props.gridData.map((item, index) => (
                        <div key={index} className="three-grid-teaser-block">
                            <div className="three-grid-image-container hidden">
                                <img src={item.image} 
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="product-text-container hidden">
                                <ul>
                                    <li className="product-title">{item.title}</li>
                                    <li className="product-description">{item.description}</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
    )
}

export default ThreeGridTeaser;
```

SASS:

```
.three-grid-teaser-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.three-grid-teaser-container {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    gap: 20px;
    @media (max-width: 1199.98px) { 
        gap: 25px;
    } 
    @media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
        width: 100%;
    } 
}
.three-grid-teaser-block {
    display: flex; 
    width: 32%;
    height: fit-content;
    @media (max-width: 1199.98px) { 
        width: 48%;
    } 
    @media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
        width:47%;
    } 
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.hover-text-underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
}

.three-grid-image-container {
    height: 300px;
    @media (max-width: 1199.98px) { 
        height: 350px;
    } 
    @media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
        height: 180px;
    }    

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.product-text-container {
    ul {
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 0;
        li:last-child {
            padding-top: 5px;
        }
        li {
            list-style: none;

        }
    }
}

.product-title {
    font-family: $terminaDemi;
    font-size: 12px;
    @media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
        font-size: 8px;
    } 
}

.product-description {
    font-family: $Montserrat;
    font-size: 18px;
    @media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
        font-size: 12px;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want each image to distort (in one direction or the other as necessary) so that it fills a square, without cropping?

Comment: i want the image to take up its container

Answer (score 1):

This is because the image has reached its maximum height in relation to the `div`. I mean, an image 300px wide and 400px high inside a 400px square `div`, in this case if you put a width of 100% in the image, the maximum that it will reach in its width is 300px, in the case of you don't want to resize it.

[Demonstração](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T6xL.png)

#### Update

'object-fit: contain' makes the image fit in the space it has proportionally available, if you want it to maintain its proportion and fill the entire space, use the 'object-fit: cover'

look at this
https://jsfiddle.net/gxnvuq6s/8/

Comment: But surely you can stretch the image to go beyond the realms of its aspect ratio and fill up the parent container.

Comment: Yes, but I thought you wanted to show the image completely, not cropped or anything like that. But you can use a 'position: absolute' in the image and in your div you can use 'overflow: hidden', to get the content of the image that passes the container to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking at the `background-size: cover;` style? you can then also position your image with `background-position: center center;`

Comment: yup it still seems to not scale the image properly it cuts it off

Comment: hmm - the problem here then comes in, setting a fixed height to your parent div and then setting the background image for that div. But @sydo has a much better solution for you with the object-fit: cover. that way you can still add SEO friendly tags to your images have it available in the search engines